# Looking for a concise treatise on the $\mathbb Z^n$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module

Tags: reference-request, modules

I am working on something which turned out to be isomorphic to the $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb Z^n$ and want to efficiently learn about its properties without needing to deal too much with more general modules or rings. I am therefore looking for a concise book, book chapter, review paper or similar on the $\mathbb Z^n$ and its module structure and features such as bases, linear maps etc.

I realise that this might be an utopistic wish, so I also welcome something that has a broader scope, e.g., $\mathbb R^n$ with $\mathbb R$ being a ring sharing many properties with $\mathbb Z$.

My prerequisites are:

- I consider myself to be knowledgable on linear algebra including more abstract topics.
- I have little knowledge of groups, rings, etc.
- English and German are fine as a language.

Comment: "module"...over what ring?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group All $\mathbb{Z}$ modules are abelian groups.

Comment: @DonAntonio: $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, then it is *exactly* the same as an abelian group: $\;\Bbb Z^n\;$ is *the* free abelian group of rank $\;n\;$ and any abelian group with up to $\;n\;$ generators is a homomorphic image of it.

Comment: Another thing you should probably read about is the structure theorem for finitely-generated abelian groups: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group

Comment: The structure of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is essentially as simple as it gets. I think what is useful information or not depends on what you are trying to _do_ with it. What were you working on when this turned up?

Comment: @TimSeguine: Describing what this about would be beyond the scope here (and much too localised). Also, I do not know yet which mathematical results (if any) matter for my application – that’s why I wanted to learn about this myself. Anyway, knowing that finitely-generated Abelian groups are equivalent already helps.

Comment: Dear @Wrzlprmft : To be clear, DonAntonio and Tim are saying that *$\Bbb Z$ modules are exactly abelian groups* and that *$\Bbb Z^n$ is a particular finitely generated abelian group*. It wouldn't be right to say that things of the form $\Bbb Z^n$ are "equivalent" to finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: Okay, I feel like we could help more to point you in the right direction if we knew what you are studying. As it stands, there is not that much more to add.

Answer (score 2):

A good choice for a type of ring "sharing many properties with $\Bbb Z$" would be any [principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain), and there is a simple classification theorem [for finitely generated modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) over such rings.

You've picked an even narrower subclass of finitely generated $\Bbb Z$ modules: that of the finitely generated free $\Bbb Z$-modules. Quite nicely, the submodules of such modules are again free modules. Concretely, the submodules of $\Bbb Z^n$ look like $\Bbb Z^k$ where $k\leq n$.

Free modules are about as nice as you can get. They have "bases" analogous to those of bases of vector spaces, and the $\Bbb Z$ linear transformations of $\Bbb Z^n\to\Bbb Z^m$ is again described by the matrices $M_{n\times m}(\Bbb Z)$.

Whatever your application is, it might be worthwhile to extend your scope to all finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-modules, a.k.a. finitely generated abelian groups. This is your best bet for what to look up in references. Most basic algebra books include the structure theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, which is just a special case of the one I mentioned for PIDs.